# ant macros: fileset as javac src element

Tags: java, ant, javac, macrodef

I have ant (1.9.4) macros which accept path-like structure as src param and when i try run it I get `'FILE_NAME.java is not a directory'`.

My build file:

```
<project name="test" default="main">
    <macrodef name="testm">
        <element name="srcdir"/>
        <sequential>
            <javac destdir="target">
                <src>
                    <srcdir/>
                </src>
            </javac>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="build-project">
        <testm>
            <srcdir>
                <fileset dir="src">
                    <include name="**/*.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </srcdir>
        </testm>
    </target>

    <target name="main" depends="build-project"/>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call macros like

```
<testm>
    <srcdir>
        <path location="src"/>
    </srcdir>
</testm>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<src>` nested under `<javac>` can't have a `<srcdir>` nested within it.

Instead, pass the `<src>` from the caller of `<testm>`...

```
<macrodef name="testm">
    <element name="srcdir"/>
    <sequential>
        <!-- Nest <srcdir> directly under <javac> -->
        <javac destdir="target">
            <srcdir/>
        </javac>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="build-project">
    <testm>
        <srcdir>
            <!-- Pass <src> directly to <javac> via the macrodef -->
            <src path="src"/>
        </srcdir>
    </testm>
</target>
```

I removed `<include name="**/*.java"/>` because `<javac>` includes all `**/*.java` files by default.

As another example, you can pass several `<javac>` options to `<testm>` with one argument...

```
<macrodef name="testm">
    <element name="javac-args"/>
    <sequential>
        <javac destdir="target">
            <javac-args/>
        </javac>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="build-project">
    <testm>
        <javac-args>
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="my.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac-args>
    </testm>
</target>
```

Comment: If i need add classpath by the same way. `<javac><srcdir/><classpath><classpathdir/></classpath></javac>`?

Comment: @wtrclr I've edited my answer with another example showing a nested `<classpath>`.